# Trying to debug ios app via crash report

Tags: ios, debugging, crash

App worked fine on emulator and devices during xcode debugging phase, but running the app as an ad-hoc distribution version it crashes immediately.
Part of the crash report is below....

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) 
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x50000010 Crashed Thread:  0 
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37859f2a objc_release + 10
1   Simple Science Tab              0x000d3036 -[ssFirstViewController didYouReg]      (ssFirstViewController.m:224)
2   Simple Science Tab              0x000d2450 -[ssFirstViewController viewDidLoad] (ssFirstViewController.m:45)
```

The method referenced in the report looks like this....

```
-(void) didYouReg {
NSString *dbtn = @"stage";

BWDB *db2;

NSDictionary * row = nil;
if ((db2 = [[BWDB alloc] initWithDBFilename:home_dbfn andTableName: dbtn])) {

    for (row in [db2 getQuery:@"SELECT reg_yes FROM reg"]) {

        ans= row[@"reg_yes"];

    }

} else {
  //  message(@"db failed to init");
}
[db2 closeDB];

}
```

I've been reading a lot of posts and tried to enable the zombie feature in xcode, but that didn't seem to show anything. I'm using xcode 4.6.1
I'd appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Which line is line 224?

Comment: Is your project ARC or manual? According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399152/bwdb-sqlite-wrapper-for-ios-arc-issues) you should try [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Comment: line 224 is line below closing bracket for this method. (just empty space  between this method and the next). Is that strange? I am using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided it seems to me that the variable `home_dbfn` is deallocated when `didYouReg` is called. If this happens only in an ad-hoc distribution, this is of course difficult to debug. The reason might be e.g. a different timing behavior an a different device. You could insert an `assert` statement or other code to make sure that `home_dbfn` is not deallocated, and then ask your beta tester to run the app again.