# Used type va_list (aka_builtin_va_list) where arithmetic or pointer type is required in BWDB.m file

Tags: xcode5

I get this error and I'm unable to run the program due to this segment of code...

```
    // build the query
NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update %@ set %@ = ? where id = ?",
                    tableName,
                    [[record allKeys] componentsJoinedByString:@" = ?, "]];
[self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] withVargs:(va_list)dValues.mutableBytes];
sqlite3_step(statement);
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

}

I'm using Bill Weinman's sqlite3 code - BWDB.m - the full code can be found here (http://bw.org/iosdata/). I Noticed this error after updating to Xcode 5.1. 
I search around but couldn't find any thing helpful. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Read this:

[BWDB sqlite wrapper for ios arc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399152/bwdb-sqlite-wrapper-for-ios-arc-issues)

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered here:

[fake va_list in ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211996/fake-va-list-in-arc)

As to the library, you'd better migrate to:

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb