# Using external library is giving error Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have imported these libraries in to project

1- BWUtilities

2- BWDB

Program is giving the error in insertRow function of BWDB library .

```
- (void) updateRow:(NSDictionary *) record forRowID:(NSNumber *) rowID {
    // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    int dictSize = [record count];

    // see comments above in insertRow:
    NSMutableData * dKeys = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: sizeof(id) * dictSize];
    NSMutableData * dValues = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: sizeof(id) * dictSize];
    [record getObjects:(__unsafe_unretained id *)dValues.mutableBytes andKeys:(__unsafe_unretained id *)dKeys.mutableBytes];

    // append the rowID for the where clause
    [dValues appendBytes:&rowID length:sizeof(id)];

    // build the query
    NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update %@ set %@ = ? where id = ?",
                        tableName,
                        [[record allKeys] componentsJoinedByString:@" = ?, "]];
    [self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] withVargs:(va_list)dValues.mutableBytes];
    sqlite3_step(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Semantic Issue Group--

1-  Used type 'va_list' (aka '__builtin_va_list') where arithmetic or pointer type is required

At this line of above function

```
 [self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] withVargs:(va_list)dValues.mutableBytes];
```

how i can remove of these errors?you can download the sample project from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnZUtIN215MWhURFE/view?usp=sharing
[image]

similar question is [Used type va_list (aka_builtin_va_list) where arithmetic or pointer type is required in BWDB.m file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383846/used-type-va-list-aka-builtin-va-list-where-arithmetic-or-pointer-type-is-requ)

Comment: Clean the project and then run the project again, see if it helps

Comment: no clean is successful but build failed with error mentioned above .

Comment: "I have imported these libraries in to project": Please explain how you imported them. Also, defined "librairies". Is it a static lib? With a `.a`? A framework ? A Pod ? Just importing files? Did you do the `#import` in that `ViewController.m`?